# Struts2 - How to stop jsp render after session.invalidate()

Tags: struts2

I need a help. I have a simple struts2 login/logout application.
For each action on struts.xml some jsp is rendered in the application. Now I have implemented the logout feature in the application and it invalidates the session properly.

But after logout if I write a particular action on URL and call the action the JSP is rendered.
I want to stop that. If Interceptors be any help.
How? Please Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16940296/573032

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633221/1654265