# CSRF implementation error in struts 6.2.0

Tags: java, struts2, csrf, struts, csrf-token

I am trying to implement CSRF in a Struts 6.2.0  project.

**`struts.xml`**

```xml
<package name="struts-security" abstract="true" extends="struts-default">
  <interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultSecurityStack" />
    
    <interceptor name="token" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenInterceptor" />
    <interceptor name="tokenSessionStore" class=  "org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor" />
  </interceptors>

  <default-interceptor-ref name = "defaultSecurityStack" />

  <global-results>
    <result name="error">/error401.jsp</result>
  </global-results>

  <global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping result="error" exception="java.lang.Exception" />
  </global-exception-mappings>
```

**`LoginAction.java`**

```java
@Namespace("/common")
@Action("Login")
@InterceptorRefs({
  @InterceptorRef("token"),
  @InterceptorRef("tokenSessionStore")
})
@Results({
  @Result(name = "input", location = "login.Login", type = "tiles"),
})
```

**`login.jsp`**

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
  <s:form  method="post" validate="true" theme="simple" name="form" id="paraFrm" >
    <s:token />
```

It is returning `invalid.token`. Because I have added return page,  it is redirecting to error page. Is there any requirement of additional code to implement token in action page or any other places.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Updated, see details below.

Answer (score 0):

To use the interceptor defined in the `struts.xml` you should add the annotation

```
@ParentPackage("struts-security")
```

---

You were trying to use a

### [`tokenSession` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.html):

> This interceptor builds off of the `TokenInterceptor`, providing advanced logic for handling invalid tokens. Unlike the normal token interceptor, this interceptor will attempt to provide intelligent fail-over in the event of multiple requests using the same session. That is, it will block subsequent requests until the first request is complete, and then instead of returning the `invalid.token` code, it will attempt to display the same response that the original, valid action invocation would have displayed if no multiple requests were submitted in the first place.
>
> Example code:
>
> ```xml
> <action name="someAction" class="com.examples.SomeAction">
>     <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>
>     <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
>     <result name="success">good_result.ftl</result>
> </action>
>
> <-- In this case, myMethod of the action class will not
>        get checked for invalidity of token -->
> <action name="someAction" class="com.examples.SomeAction">
>     <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
>         <param name="excludeMethods">myMethod</param>
>     </interceptor-ref name="tokenSession>
>     <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
>     <result name="success">good_result.ftl</result>
> </action>
> ```

As you see in the examples you were missing some basic interceptors.

---

These interceptors are defined in the `struts-default` package which is inherited. So, you shouldn't override them. Just remove these interceptors from the `<interceptors>` tag, or use `<intetceptor-ref>` tag instead.
Only one *token* interceptor should be configured to the action. Because both is using the same token from the browser, so they are mutually exclusive.

```xml
<interceptor name="token" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenInterceptor" />
<interceptor name="tokenSessionStore" class=  "org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor" />
```

---

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16940296/573032) answer if you want to create a custom interceptor stack and use it to every action.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: it is directly redirecting to error page.

Comment: You said it returns an `invalid.token` result code. `it will attempt to display the same response that the original...`. How error page can be returned? What is the error code?

Comment: as I already mentioned above that It is returning invalid.token. Because I have added return page, it is redirecting to error page.

Comment: Of course it returns invalid.token because you have two token interceptors in the stack. One of them removes a token from the request another asumes that there's no token is submitted.